# Will a Insert or Update query affect from indexed columns which are not included in query?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, indexing

Mysql and SQL users. This question related to both of you. Its about indexing. I have this table structure for a classified website. I have a one common table to store title, description, user who post etc.. Also I have this table structure to store detail attributes about a particular ad category.

```
CREATE TABLE `ad_detail` (
  `ad_detail_id_pk` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `header_id_fk` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `brand_id_fk` smallint(5) NULL,
  `brand_name` varchar(200) NULL,
  `is_brand_new` bool,
  .......
  `transmission_type_id_fk` tinyint(3) NULL,
  `transmission_type_name` varchar(200) NULL,
  `body_type_id_fk` tinyint(3) unsigned NULL,
  `body_type_name` varchar(200) NULL,
  `mileage` double NULL,
  `fuel_type_id_fk` tinyint(3) NULL,
  ......
  PRIMARY KEY (`ad_detail_id_pk`)
)
```

SO as you can see first part of the attributes will belong to mobile ads and second part belongs to vehicle ads like so on I have other attributes for other categories. header_id_fk will hold the relationship to header table which have common information. So all of these foreign keys are some what involves in filtering ads. Some may wants to find all the mobile phones which made by Nokia. SO then the brand_id_fk will be use. Some may wants to filter vehicle by fuel type. So as you can see I need to index every filtering attributes in this table. So now this is my question.

So when user post a mobile ad insert statement will contain certain no of fields to store data. But as we all know index will gain the performance when  data retrieval but it will make additional cost to insert and update queries. So if I insert mobile ad, will that insert query suffer from other attributes which are relevant to vehicles ads' index fields?

Comment: Why do you have both `brand_id` and `brand_name` (and other pairs) in _this_ table?  The `name` should be _only_ in the other table.

Comment: See the EAV tag I added.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, normal indexes contain one row for every row in the table (unless you use [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/null). So therefore every index will have a new row inserted every time you insert a row into the table, and the associated index maintenance issues (page splits etc.)

You could create a [filtered](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/09/filtered-indexes-and-is-not-null/)/partial index which excludes nulls which would solve the particular issue of `INSERT` performance being slowed down by indexes on fields into which you're inserting `NULL` but you would need to test the solution thoroughly to make sure that the indexes are still being used by the queries that you expect them to be used. Note that [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) does not support partial indexes, AFAIK, the following is for [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server).

```
Create Index ix_myFilteredIndex On ad_detail (brand_id_fk) Where brand_id_fk Is Not Null;
```